# Wordpress categories not working throughout site

Tags: php, categories, archives

Lately, I upgraded by Wordpress website to version 4.6.1 and I not sure if that caused issue or something else, but my site is no longer able to filter out posts on the basis of `categories`.

When I visit my category archive page using `www.mysite.com/category/some-category`, it shows 404 page. Though I am able to assign categories to post, but apart from not being able to filter on categories in the front-end, when I filter using dropdown in the All Post (in wp-admin/edit.php), I get a blank list eventhough I have post assigned to those categories.

Not sure if this has something to do with `.htaccess` rewrite or `SEO` plugin as suggested in posts but I've tries tweaking these up with no success.

Comment: if you don't include any code that might be messing with categories and permalinks we here cannot offer anything but wild guesses.

Comment: @cjbj, I am not at all aware of the issue and from where I should post the code. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Sorry, I have no all seeing eye which allows me to scan the harddisk of your server to see which themes and plugins you have installed.

Comment: @cjbj, I really did not mean to ask you to scan the servers hard disk. I was just trying to ask from where should I post the code (if its the .htaccess, plugin, archive.php... etc). I am aware of the Stack Overflow "asking question best practices" and I am also aware that I should post codes as well, but a wordpress installation has over thousand files and if I had any Idea where to look for, I would not had asked such a dumb question here. Sorry and I am not trying to be offensive. But thats the fact.

Comment: What are your settings under Settings -> Permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

Quite often, after WP or plugin updates, just re-saving the Settings->Permalinks works for me (without changing anything).